# 401 error with TypeScript mapping files in SharePoint 2010

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, typescript

I have a SharePoint 2010 WebPart with typescript files. I have confirmed that the .ts, .map AND .js files are all deployed to the appropriate folder and I can access the .map file, .js file and .ts files via the browser, but in the Network tab in Canary I see 401 errors for each of the .map files in the WebPart.

So far, I've tried to set the Browser File Handling setting in Central Administration to Permissive and also tried to the instructions at http://www.chaholl.com/archive/2013/01/03/typescript-in-a-sharepoint-farm-solution.aspx to no avail.

How can I get TypeScript debugging to work in a SharePoint 2010 WebPart using Canary?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get this working by having the map files in a local location rather than relying on getting them from the server.

You will need to update the path in the JavaScript files to point to your local map files to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, by setting the `Build Action` to `Content` in the file properties for each of the files (.map, .ts and .js), I was able to get Chrome to debug the .ts files. I also had to ensure that all of my JavaScript files had this setting - I had initially neglected to include some of the files.

In short, ensure all of your related JavaScript files are present in the output folder.